# PHP sort array by key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this output:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [username] => bla1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [username] => bla2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6
        [username] => bla3
    )

)
```

How can i sort the 3 arrays inside this outside array by 'username'?

This is what i tried:

```
if($this->needOrder) {
   $sorted = [];

   foreach($files as $file) {
     $sorted[] = asort($tableFile);
   }

   return $sorted;
 }
```

`$files` has the content of the ^above code. The `asort()` is only for testing if it works.
But my return is:

```
Array
(
  [0] => 1
  [1] => 1
  [2] => 1
)
```

Comment: StackOveflow is around to help you solve issues with your implementations. Please, provide samples of what you've attempted and we can hint you towards the right direction.

Comment: You would have to tell us what your goal is! Also you want to read this: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php :D You can try to figure it out yourself

Comment: Use the `usort` function. Write a comparison function that compares `$a['username']` with `$b['username']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [***usort()***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
$arr = Array(
    array('id' => 4,'username' => 'bla2'),
    array('id' => 5,'username' => 'bla3'),
    array('id' => 6,'username' => 'bla1'),
);

function custom_sort($a, $b)
{
    return strnatcmp($a['username'], $b['username']);
}

usort($arr, "custom_sort");

print '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
print '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [username] => bla1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [username] => bla2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [username] => bla3
    )

)
```