# Php, sort an multidimensionnal array by a value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this array :

```
$myarray
(
    [5] => Array
        (
            [count] => 2
            [aaa] => 119
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [count] => 5
            [aaa] => 90
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [count] => 7
            [aaa] => 91
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [count] => 12
            [aaa] => 119
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [count] => 8
            [aaa] => 119
        )
)
```

I want sort this array by the "count" value for get the three id (the key) that have the biggest counter.

With my exemple :

```
print_r(customfunction($myarray))
// display : array(4,1,3)
```

Because [4] have count = 12, [4] have count = 8, and [4] have count = 7. 
How can I sort my array ? and get the three id that have the biggest counster ?

Thank you =)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP sort array by key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27691470/php-sort-array-by-key)

Comment: What have you tried? You should add some actual sorting code, if you have tried.

Comment: 1. [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php), [`uasort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) if you need to preserve your array indexes. 2. [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php), maybe preceded with [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) if you're only interested in the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for usefull links :)

This is the solution !

```
function cmp($a, $b){
  if ($a['count'] > $b['count']){
    return -1;
  } elseif($a['count'] < $b['count']){
    return 1;
  } else return 0;
}

...

uasort($myarray, "cmp");
```